# Four bulb t12 light fixture

Tags: lighting

I’m working on some wiring in an old house and this four bulb t12 light isn’t working so I test it and nothing so I get up above it and find some 10/3 in the ceiling box. Why is 10/3 in this box when it should be 12/2 and can you use 10/3 to run this type of circuit

Comment: You can always use larger gauge wire, it is usually just more expensive and harder to use.  The size of the breaker usually determines the smallest size wire you can use, 14 gauge with 15 amp, 12 gauge for 20 amp breaker.

Comment: Why is the 10/3 causing an issue for you?

Comment: Check the size of breaker to see if they just used larger wire or tried a no-no and spliced off a 30 amp circuit.

Comment: Also, get rid of the T12 fixture and put in LED.

Comment: Maybe planning on installing ceiling fan with switched light

Comment: The 10/3 is on a 20 amp breaker it is not causing a problem per-say I had just never seen something done that way and didn’t want a fire or something to happen. I will be running the rest of that line today I also want to know what else it goes to. I’ll let you know when I find out thanks for the help and advice

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem with the bigger wire gauge. But I would check the breaker to make sure they fused it down to 20A or less. You can't put light fixtures on a 30 amp circuit in residential.

The only time bigger wire is a problem is when it's too big for the mechanical lugs or device it's supplying. You could wire your whole house in #10 copper if you wanted to. Switches and receptacles are rated for #10. But that would be just silly.

Comment: Silly and expensive.

Comment: Definitely a waste of money. I once did a job for the air force and in their offices, everything had to be #10 stranded in EMT.

Comment: Surprised they didn't want rigid.

Comment: They require it for data and security cameras but not electrical.

Answer (score 4):

3-wire cable in a light fixture could exist for a variety of legitimate reasons.  For instance a modern *switch loop* uses 3-wire cable between light and switch. Or it could be powered by one leg of a *multi-wire branch circuit*.

#10 cable in a 20A circuit could exist for a variety of reasons. For instance, the circuit may be traveling a long distance.  hat's what the person had left over.  Or it is aluminum or copper-clad aluminum in which case #10 is the correct wire size for 20A.

To know for sure, we would need to know what is going on in the rest of the circuit.

There is a temptation among novices to use the word "wrong" to describe any work they do not understand.  In my experience on this forum that has about a 50% chance of being accurate and a 50% chance of it being simply a valid technique you haven't learned of yet.   It's common to have plenty of both.